# How to install rpm package without converting into deb

Tags: deb, rpm

When I am trying to convert rpm into deb, following warnings appeared:

```
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
warning: libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 80420f66: NOKEY
libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm is for architecture i386 ; the package cannot be built on this system
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Your title and body do not share the same problem. And why would you go through all this trouble? See http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/vivid/libgmt-dev for 4.5.12 or http://packages.ubuntu.com/nl/wily/libgmt-dev for 5.1.2

Comment: Sorry,  I am not able to follow you.  I downloaded "libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm" package and I am supposed to install is this package in "/usr/lib". What is the best way to do this? Thanks for your response.

Comment: WHY would you download software for -Redhat- if there are versions for Ubuntu available? There is no "best" way to do this. It is not logical what you are doing.

Comment: I am getting following error during installation:

Comment: (Reading database ... 288170 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libgmt-dev_4.5.12-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgmt-dev (4.5.12-1) over (4.5.11-1build1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgmt-dev:
 libgmt-dev depends on libgmt4 (= 4.5.12-1); however:
  Version of libgmt4 on system is 4.5.11-1build1.

dpkg: error processing package libgmt-dev (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libgmt-dev

Answer (score 1):

With a working internet connection, please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgmt-dev
```

The package and all its dependencies in the correct (.deb) format will be correctly installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use rather Ubuntu repositories or if you really need the very latest version of the software, which may not be present in Ubuntu repos- build it from sources.

Some packages can be converted from rpm to deb, but yes - it may involve some troubles.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to build a 32 bits package (i386) on a 64 bits system, as the last log line suggest :

```
libgmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.i586.rpm is for architecture i386 ; the package cannot be built on this system
```

Did you try with the 64bits version of the package ? (which seems to be `lib64gmt-devel-4.5.9-3.mga4.x86_64.rpm`)